# How can I save each item in a "select multiple" field in its own MySQL record (using Rails)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Thanks for any help you can provide! I have a Ruby on Rails application where I am trying to save maps with driving directions and waypoints. The data needs to come straight out of the entry form instead of the Google Maps javascript. I've solved the starting and ending points, but the waypoints are giving me a problem.

**My questions:**

1. How can I save each waypoint in its own record in the Waypoint table? I'm able to get the first waypoint into the table, but the rest of the "select multiple" options are ignored.
2. How can I make each waypoint.newsavedmap_id field the same as its corresponding newsavedmaps id so that I can call these up later?

**HTML**

```
    <p>Enter a street address, city, and state:
    <input id="startinput" type="text" name="starthere" size="56"></p>
    <p>Or, select a location from the list:
    <select id="startdrop" name="startthere">
          <option value="">
          <% for masterlocation in @masterlocation %>
          <option value="<%= masterlocation.street_address %> <%= masterlocation.city %>, <%= masterlocation.state %>, <%= masterlocation.zip %>"><%= masterlocation.place_name %></option>
                    <% end %>
                </select></p>

    <div><b>Stops</b></div>
    <div id="multiselectdiv1">  
    <select multiple id="waypoints" name="waypointsselected">
        <% for masterlocation in @masterlocation %>
    <option value="<%= masterlocation.street_address %> <%= masterlocation.city %>, <%= masterlocation.state %>, <%= masterlocation.zip %>"><%= masterlocation.place_name %></option>
                    <% end %>
    </select>               
    </div>
    <b>End</b>
    <p>Enter a street address, city, and state:
    <input id="endinput" type="text" name="endhere" size="56"></p>
    <p>Or, select a location from the list:
    <select id="enddrop" name="endthere">
    <option value="">
    <% for masterlocation in @masterlocation %>
    <option value="<%= masterlocation.street_address %> <%= masterlocation.city %>, <%= masterlocation.state %>, <%= masterlocation.zip %>"><%= masterlocation.place_name %></option>
                    <% end %>
                </select></p>
    </div>
    <div>    
    <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();" id="showmapview" value="Show Map">
    </div>
```

I have two MySQL tables. The first is newsavedmaps:

```
    id  
    itinerary_id
    start   
    start_lat   
    start_long  
    start_masterlocation_id
    end
    end_lat
    end_long
    end_masterlocation_id   
    name
```

The second is waypoints:

```
    id
    newsavedmap_id
    waypoint
    waypoint_lat
    waypoint_long
    waypoint_masterlocation_id
```

The two are meant to be connected by newsavedmaps.id and waypoint.newsavedmap_id .

My newsavedmap_controller.rb includes:

```
    def create

@newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new(params[:newsavedmap])


@newsavedmap.name = params[:newsavedmapname]

if !params[:starthere].blank?
  @newsavedmap.start = params[:starthere]
else
  @newsavedmap.start = params[:startthere]
end

if !params[:endhere].blank?
  @newsavedmap.end = params[:endhere]
else
  @newsavedmap.end = params[:endthere]
end

if !params[:waypointsselected].blank?
  @waypoint = Waypoint.new(params[:waypoint])
  @waypoint.waypoint = params[:waypointsselected]
end
```

**Edit 1**

In response to Colinm's suggestion to wrap the controller in an iterator to get separate records for each address, I tried this, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing the wrong thing:

```
    if !params[:waypointsselected].blank?
  for waypoint in @waypoint
  @waypoint = Waypoint.new(params[:waypoint])
  @waypoint.waypoint = params[:waypointsselected]
  @waypoint.newsavedmap = @newsavedmap
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I save each waypoint in its own record in the Waypoint table? I'm able to get the first waypoint into the table, but the rest of the "select multiple" options are ignored.

Unless you have a really good reason not to, use Rails' form helpers instead of rolling your own form fields. They will take care of this automatically, as well as handle edge cases you may not even know about. (Like the gotcha that sending a multiple select back with no selections will leave the record unchanged. That doesn't sound like it's an issue in your use case, but Rails still has your back if you use the form helpers.)

In your case, you'd simply pass `multiple: true` in the html_options hash, like so:

```
<%= f.select :waypointsselected,
    MasterLocation.waypoints_for_select,
    {},
    { multiple: true } 
%>
```

Note that this does assume you implement a `waypoints_for_select` method. Without seeing all the code, it looks like you have way too much logic in your view right now. It's brittle and verbose to construct the options array in the view; offloading that to the model or a helper keeps your view code cleaner and helps eliminate potential future bugs.

If you absolutely can't/absolutely don't want to use form helpers in this application, the key you're looking for is `[]`. Rails sensibly assumes a form field represents a single value unless you explicitly denote it as an array. Just tack an empty array on the end of the field name:

```
<select multiple id="waypoints" name="waypointsselected[]">
```

...and that field's key in the params hash will instead contain an array of values representing the selected items:

```
{ waypointsselected: ["3", "6", "9"] }
```

As for associating the `waypoint`s with the `newsavedmap`s, just set it explicitly during creation. You're almost there:

```
if !params[:waypointsselected].blank?
  @waypoint = Waypoint.new(params[:waypoint])
  @waypoint.waypoint = params[:waypointsselected]
  # You can do it like this...
  @waypoint.newsavedmap = @newsavedmap
  # Or using the ID...
  @waypoint.newsavedmap_id = @newsavedmap.id
end
```

(I haven't adapted this code to deal with the fact you now have an array of values in `waypointsselected`; I just plugged the relationship definitions into your existing code. Remember to adjust your code to expect an array and iterate over it.)

Comment: Colinm, thanks so much for your help! I'm going to check out the second part of your answer in a second, but I ran into an issue using []. This creates a single record with all of the addresses instead of multiple records with individual addresses. Is there a way to get multiple records?

Comment: Drat, you beat my edit! :) I didn't modify the controller code to deal with an array; wrap it up in an iterator and you should be good.

Comment: Colinm, I've tried wrapping the controller in an iterator, but I'm sure I've done it wrong (I'm very new to Rails and am trying to rewire someone else's project.) Will you check my edit? Also, not sure if it's related, but only waypoint.newsavedmap = newsavedmap works for me. For some reason, the other option doesn't (thanks, though!)